# Merge two UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, uitableview, merge

I have the following scenario I need to find solution for - I have two UITableViews with customer Controller classes:

A) One of them has static cells and controls a list of settings in the app - like setting name, email and phone.
B) The other one is using cell prototypes, displaying a list of categories, the user can subscribe to.

Now I have to merge those two views, so the list of categories is displayed below the name, email and phone settings input fields. The two controllers have completely different functionality, both have save buttons on the top-right and it will be a nice little mess if I try to merge them into one.
This looks like a challenge so it will be really cool if I can get some tips how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried,Any code?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I would like to have some conceptual solution first and then start implementing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the categories belongs to some NSArray.

Why not create two sections and display those cells in the seconds sections?

Obviously you don't need to merge the cells -> you need to merge the data they are built on.